# Get display value of input when it is diffeerent then model value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using currency mask module and have code like below

```
    <input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" #myInput = "ngModel" [options]="{ prefix: 'R$ ', thousands: ',', decimal: '.' }"/>

{{myInput.value}}
```

currecnymask formats the data user types in format of currency. I want to display the formatted value below the text box. But it does print same value what user entered. Is there a way to get the formatted value?

Comment: make use of getter and setter here to set the updated value when it set by the input box

Comment: All is taken care of by the directive

Comment: can you create a plunker for the same

Comment: I though that's why the pipes exist :)